# Html anchor tag

Tags: html, css

Do I need to wrap a tag (a href="#") in a `<p>` tag? I guess it can be wrapped in any block level element like div but I'm not sure.

Comment: Really depends on the context - more information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an inline element and doesn't have to be wrapped anywhere.

The page body is already a block-level element, so anything you have inside it is respectively wrapped by it.

Comment: The body element is defined differently in different versions of HTML. In Strict it is defined as `<!ELEMENT BODY O O (%block;|SCRIPT)+ +(INS|DEL) -- document body -->` and may not have `<a>` elements as children.

Answer (score 1):

No. If you want to make the anchor element block level you use the css property display: block;

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/mail" title="Google Web Mail" style="display: block;">Google Mail</a>
```

You can wrap an anchor in a p element if you want to do something like:

`<p>My favorite search engine is <a href="http://www.google.com" title="Google Search Engine">Google</a>, because it allows me to fine tune my search</p>`